# How can I kick off a user to an Excel spreadsheet being used as an attachment to an e-mail from a SQL job?

Tags: sql-server, excel, sql-job

I have an Excel spreadsheet that updates when it opens by calling stored procedures from our SQL database.  I have a SQL server job that runs background procedures and then sends an e-mail with that Excel file as an attachment.  The problem is that there are users that have the Excel file open.  When the SQL job runs, it fails because the Excel file can't be used as an attachment because it is open.  Is there anyway I can kick off any users of the Excel file?  I'd be open to doing this either from the SQL job or from a setting in the Excel file.

Here's the error from the SQL job:
"Failed to open attachment file '\server\Excel File.xlsm'. Executing API 'CreateFile' failed with error number 32. [SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 22051).  The step failed.

Comment: Surely the email recipients aren't using the Excel file which resides on the server?  They should have their own copies from the email attachment...  If the server file is locked it's more likely a server-side process has it open.

Comment: This sounds a lot like an [xy problem](http://xyproblem.info/) to me.